# Is global non-convex optimization NP-complete?

Tags: optimization, np-complete, np, decision-problem, mathematical-programming

Assume I have some non-convex function $f(x_1, x_2, ...)$ and I want to optimize it to find a global minimum. I feel like it is easy to show that this problem is in the class **NP** with the decision problem

*Is there a set of points such that f < C?*

Where C is some constant. However, I am not sure if these problems are in the class of **NP-Complete**, and if so, what would you say the size of the input is? Complexity of the function?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not straightforward to figure out how to formalize this in terms where NP-completeness is applicable.  What are the inputs, and what are the desired outputs?  Is $f$ fixed, or part of the input?  If $f$ is fixed, please specify the function $f$ in the question.  If it's part of the input, how is the function $f$ specified?   What's the type signature of $f$?  Is it continuous ($f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) or discrete?   If it is discrete and specified as a truth table, that takes exponential space, which is problematic.   If it id continuous, it can't be specified as a truth table.

Comment: To show that your problem is NP-hard, try encoding SAT as a non-convex optimization problem.

Comment: Even a QP problem with one negative eigenvalue is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard, see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00120662

Comment: However, the answer depends on your function. There are nonconvex functions easy to optimize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, non-convex optimization is NP-hard. For a simple proof, consider the following reduction from Subset-Sum. The Subset-Sum problem asks whether there is a subset of the input integers $a_1, \dots, a_n$ which sums to zero. To reduce to non-convex programming, let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be variables encoding the subset and consider the following non-convex program:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize }\quad&(a\cdot x)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2(1 - x_i)^2\\
\text{subject to}\quad& \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Note that the optimum of this program is zero iff the Subset-Sum instance has a subset which sums to zero.

Comment: If one want's to convert this into an unconstrained problem, just add a small enough bump function at 0 to the objective.

Comment: A different way to obtain an unconstrained problem, replace $(a\cdot x)^2$ with $\left(a\cdot x-\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots + a_n}2\right)^2$ and you obtain a reduction from the (bi-)partition problem.

Comment: Leaving note for my own reference: The second term in the expression to minimize is $0$ when $x_i =1$ or $x_i=0$. At all other $x_i$ values, it is $>0$ due to the square. Similarly the minimum attainable value for $(a\cdot x)^2$ is also $0$. Hence the entire expression can be $0$ if some subset of $a_i$'s has zero sum. As finding the minima will have at least as much complexity as the problem of checking if $0$ is a minima, the problem of finding the minima is also NP.

Answer (score 3):

[Quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) is an example of a non-convex optimization problem that is NP-hard.  See [Transforming SAT to Quadratic Programming in polynomial time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/17946/755) for a proof.